# Did I write this function wrong? Can someone tell me where I am making my mistake?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Here is the function:**

```
 <?php
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','test123','joomla');

 function parseDescription($id)
 {
    $sql = "SELECT raw_description FROM n0dap_jevents_vevdetail WHERE evdet_id='$id'";
            $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
            {
            return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
            }
     }              
     ?>
```

**Here are the Errors:**

Notice: Undefined variable: connect in C:\xampp\htdocs\Try\includes\function.inc.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Try\includes\function.inc.php on line 6

Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Try\includes\function.inc.php on line 7

*If I convert all this the Mysql instead of Mysqli it works but then all my regular expressions are all messed up. I've been at this for a few hours which pretty much tells you I'm a novice and really could use some help.*

Comment: `$connect` is defined outside the function scope, so inside the function it's `undefined`. The other errors are a consequence of it

Comment: The error message is pretty clear, check php variable scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. Note that when using `mysql_*` you don't need to pass the connection to the functions and the scope of the db connection is global, that's why that worked...

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, your `connect` variable is defined outside the scope of the function and so it's not able to make use of it. You'll need to pass that variable in to your function as a parameter like this:

```
 $connect = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','test123','joomla');

 function parseDescription($id, $connect)
 {
    // Your connection code
 }
```

Comment: And what does the function return when the if statement is false?

Comment: @Rizier123 I know that you have good reputation in SO site, but try not to discourage someone.. if you have better answers than give your knowledge. not your tots... with regards...

Comment: @Rizier123 Isn't that a bit out of the scope of the question? ;-)

Comment: @Bulk Exactly this it the point!, it doesn't have a return statement if the if statement fails, so I think it's good to return always something

Comment: Certainly, although that wasn't OP's question. I didn't really see the point in critiquing his code that would invariably work with this solution (note I didn't even include the function contents in my answer) - feel free to improve it though if you want :)

Comment: @jeroen I follow a simple principle: `If you see a piece of code which you can improve, leave it better behind that you saw it the first time`, so I through it in here that I think the function should return something in both cases

Comment: @Rizier123 Without more context we don't know if the OP is not testing or relying on that behaviour. You could also talk about sql injection when injecting variables in queries, but for that we really would need to see all the code. But yes, I tend to return things from functions always as well :-)

Answer (score 1):

This can be a bit difficult than regular functional programming, but `oop` is good way for managing your code..

Here I have declared $connect as a **private variable** of the class

Let me know if any further help needed regarding `oop`..

```
<?php

class MyClass
{
    private $connect;
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'test123', 'joomla');
    }

    function parseDescription($id)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT raw_description FROM n0dap_jevents_vevdetail WHERE evdet_id='$id'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connect, $sql);
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
        {
            return mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}

$object = new MyClass();
$answer = $object->parseDescription($id);
if($answer)
{
  // do your stuff here
}
?>
```

Comment: *Please try this and let me know..* Should that mean that OP has to try out that code? I thought you wrote the answer not OP! (BTW: Just to use global is not a good practice!)

Comment: @Rizier123 what if it does not work?? Than i will try to help OP out with another solutions....

Comment: In modern programming there is very little reason to make use of the `global` keyword, please don't promote it's use :)

Comment: Code-only answers are not that useful, you should explain why this would work where the OP's code does not. Apart from that global variables are a terrible solution IMO.

Comment: @Bulk yep I know.. I suggested this because after reading the question this solution blink in my mind.. will delete my answer

Comment: @NishantSolanki You don't have to delete it just edit it and improve it!

Comment: Much better @NishantSolanki :)